# C++ cURL linking error "unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, curl, unresolved-external

I am facing issues with the C++ cUrl Library on Windows, using Visual Studio 2012.

I have a **CGI** project which generates a .cgi file. This project includes another project called **Library** which is a **Static Library Project**.

In the **Library** project, I have the code which uses cUrl and includes `curl/curl.h`. I have referenced the **Preprocessor Definition** `CURL_STATICLIB`.

Then in my **CGI Project**, I have linked `libcurl.lib` to my project in **Configuration Properties > Linker > Additional Dependencies**.

But when I try to build the Solution, I still have those errors :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_setopt in Library.lib(fct_util.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_perform in Library.lib(fct_util.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_init in Library.lib(fct_util.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_cleanup in Library.lib(fct_util.obj)
```

I already took a look at this topic : [Unresolved symbols when linking a program using libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176503/unresolved-symbols-when-linking-a-program-using-libcurl), as well as other related topics but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Am I missing something ?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Credit to this guy helped me get further than any docs.

Still have a couple more issues.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjNyT5PhNvI

Then do this , someone in the video comments 
Very important after you do everything in video.
Need to navigate back to solution right click properties
(see below comment)

"Thanks , it worked after i added Normaliz.lib;Ws2_32.lib;Wldap32.lib;Crypt32.lib;advapi32.lib in Additional Dependencies(property->linker->input)"