# Curl link issue

Tags: php, c++, curl

When implementing a program to post and read webpage data (in C++), I'm getting the following errors linking `curl` during compilation:

> ```
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function "public: __thiscall WebBrowser::WebBrowser(struct HWND__ *)" (??0WebBrowser@@QAE@PAUHWND__@@@Z)
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function "public: __thiscall WebBrowser::WebBrowser(struct HWND__ *)" (??0WebBrowser@@QAE@PAUHWND__@@@Z)
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt referenced in function "public: __thiscall WebBrowser::WebBrowser(struct HWND__ *)" (??0WebBrowser@@QAE@PAUHWND__@@@Z)
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall WebBrowser::WebBrowser(struct HWND__ *)" (??0WebBrowser@@QAE@PAUHWND__@@@Z)
> ```

I'm using visual studio 2008 and used this command to build:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static WITH_SSL=static WITH_DEVEL=C:\OpenSSL-Win32 VC=X ENABLE_SSPI=no ENABLE_IDN=no ENABLE_WINSSL=no DEBUG=no MACHINE=x86 GEN_PDB=no ENABLE_IPV6=yes
```

It's notable that I used 2015 visual studio to build the package `7.47.0`.

Add the library in the project configuration dialog:

```
Project->Properties (or Alt+F7),->Configuration properties->Linker->Input->Additional library dependencies.

Project->Properties (or Alt+F7),->Configuration properties->Linker->General->Additional library directories
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The library is not linked properly.
The error looks similar to this:
[Unresolved symbols when linking a program using libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176503/unresolved-symbols-when-linking-a-program-using-libcurl)