# VS 2013 Libcurl error

Tags: c++, libcurl

```
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt
```

Hi, I have added the include dir the lib dir and in the linker- > input I have added the libcurl.lib, now I am gettings this errors.

Comment: Why you mark as duplicate? Where is the answer in the another topic for my question? Its totally different....

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176503/unresolved-symbols-when-linking-a-program-using-libcurl

Comment: "Looks like the libraries are not being successfully linked. Ensure the library directory is set to include the full path to the libcurl dll. Also make sure this library is actually added to your project."

Its added into my project, lib is linked, path is okey. I always search in the google and everywhere before I ask, I tryed to fix it for 2 hours, than I asked here.

Comment: I still have this problem, I have read ALL of the pages here which talks about any curl function in c++.... I have a working http sender method... but when I enter the game, and the function start to work the game lose the connection, so I dont know why but the HTTP socket connection dropping my game socket connection. Thats why I am looking for help..