# CURL Static Link Unresolved External Symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, visual-studio-2017

I built CURL static lib from source using this command in the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt Visual Studio

> nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static MACHINE=AMD64

I added the lib folder to the linker library folder, added libcurl_a.lib to the linker input, and added the include folder to additional include directories. I also used the pre-processor define CURL_STATICLIB.

The library links successfully and the header is found. But I get 60 unresolved external symbols when I try to compile. https://hastebin.com/vukekakoti.tex

Dynamic linking is working with no problems.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I followed all instructions for building and linking curl. Please explain why I was downvoted. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the undefined symbols, figure out what libraries they belong to, and add those libraries to your linker input.

Comment: WSA looks like windows socket api, but I'm still perplexed as to how I can make the DLL and it runs perfectly, but using the lib doesnt compile.

Comment: I've whittled away at some of the missing external definitions. Now I'm down to two. I'll post a list. Still curious as to why my thing runs with the DLL and why the DLL even compiles if these external definitions are missing.

Comment: "how I can make the DLL and it runs perfectly" the curl dll already links to all other necessary dlls, but static libraries can't reference other libraries, they don't work this way.

Comment: i thought the dll was built from the same static libraries.

Comment: They are of course.

Comment: The link to the error message is know invalid. And without the error message the question is **incomplete**. (This is why it is important to put error message **directly** into the question post when ask.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing definitions contained in these libraries:

> libcurl_a.lib;ws2_32.lib;wldap32.lib;advapi32.lib;kernel32.lib;comdlg32.lib;crypt32.lib;normaliz.lib

Add those to your additional dependencies.

Comment: On a side note, I'm wondering if this is poor documentation by curl team or if it's normal to expect users to hunt for missing libs when compiling a library.

Comment: I am wondering where do these lib files come from, I expected them to be in either the windows folder or the visual studio folder but neither seems the case.

Comment: why do you need to include another libcur_a.lib for static library?

Answer (score 0):

if compiling CURL with static linking, you will need to specify on the preprocessor field:

> CURL_STATICLIB

and also as mentioned above, you`ll need to link with dependent libraries.