# how can i fix undefined reference to '_imp_curl_easy_setopt' in c?

Tags: c

extracting the curl folder in include path project and include them in code  then copy the content of lib folder there is two files **'libcurl.a,libcurl.dll.a'** into lib path in **mingw** and linked it using eclipse ide.

> properties>c/c++ build>settings>MinGW c linker>libraries

Comment: It sounds like you didn't set the correct linker library? Can you please give more details?

Comment: i edited my post with a new info.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to link with curl statically or to link with curl import library both files have the suffix ".lib" so it is a little confusing.

If you are trying to link with curl static library, you need to have the define CURL_STATICLIB defined at your project pre-processor definition.

Comment: no there is no file with .lib in zib folder that i loaded it from 'https://curl.haxx.se/' just I am trying by adding .a files.

Comment: I see this issue was already discussed. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176503/unresolved-symbols-when-linking-a-program-using-libcurl