# How do you properly install libcurl for use in visual studio 2017?

Tags: curl, visual-c++, libcurl

I am just starting out in c++ and cannot figure out how to add libraries, in particular libcurl.  I tried a bunch of tutorials but most were for 2013/10 or didn't work.  Can anyone please explain (Preferably in standard/non technical English) how I can add the library? I have already tried adding it in the include section of the program and in the additional dependencies menu.

Note this is a re-post I asked virtually the same question around 3 days ago to which I received no replies.  Not sure if that is because its very easy and I should have figured it out my self, or if it just got buried in a flood of questions, or some other reason.  In any case sorry for the re-post.

Answer (score 60):

Here's how I've got curl to work with Visual Studio 2017 15.9.14:

1. Download curl zip package from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html (latest verified is: https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.70.0.zip)
2. Extract downloaded package to a folder of your choice (e.g. `C:\curl\`)
3. Open `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` (see Windows Start menu or `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\`) and `cd` to `C:\curl\winbuild\`
4. Run `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static`. This will build curl as a static library into `C:\curl\builds\libcurl-vc-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\`
5. Create a new project in Visual Studio (e.g. a `Windows Console Application`)
6. In Project `Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories` add `C:\curl\builds\libcurl-vc-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\include\`
7. In Project `Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories` add `C:\curl\builds\libcurl-vc-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\` there
8. In Project `Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` add `libcurl_a.lib`, `Ws2_32.lib`, `Crypt32.lib`, `Wldap32.lib` and `Normaliz.lib`
9. Try to build a sample program:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl\curl.h>

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can use vcpkg to install curl:

1. Get latest vcpkg zip file from https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/releases (e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/archive/2019.09.zip) and extract it to a folder of your choice (e.g. C:\vcpkg\)
2. Open `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` (see Windows Start menu or `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\`) and `cd` to `C:\vcpkg\`
3. Run `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
4. Run `vcpkg.exe integrate install`
5. Run `vcpkg.exe install curl`
6. Create a new C++ project in Visual Studio and you're ready to go - try it with the example above. There's no need to modify project settings.

Comment: Yeah this solution actually works perfectly. Cost me 8 hours to find and figure out. I never get CURL on Windows with OpenSSL support compiled. Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: @DigitalHuman If you are still interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrLEIRChf84 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pF8GjMBcmA

Comment: Hi! I am interested in building libcurl as a static lib with https support. I followed the instructions for the first option downloading https://curl.haxx.se/download.html, but there is no such Makefile.vs file, can't run nmake. Would you provide me a libcurl version (maybe an older one) that contained such file? Thanks

Comment: @notNullGothik download the zip file (the latest one is https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.69.1.zip) and unzip it. Makefile.vs is inside of the winbuild subfolder.

Comment: followed all steps, now I get `cannot open source file "curl\curl.h"`

Comment: I followed every step of first method and while I do have libcurl_a.lib i am missing the other lib files such as Ws2_32.lib
However i used vcpkg following your instruction and it did work. Thanks

Comment: @user Ws2_32.lib, Crypt32.lib, Wldap32.lib and Normaliz.lib are Windows SDK files

Comment: Amazing answer! The alternative way worked for me. I only add that if you want 64-bit version, use `vcpkg install curl:x64-windows` in step 5.

Comment: Also add Properties -> C++ -> Preprocessor -> CURL_STATICLIB