# How to build libcurl in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: libcurl, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build libcurl in Visual Studio 2019 following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680718/6936706 and I get an error in step 4:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\builds\libcurl-vc-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\vssh\libssh2.obj'
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and replace winbuild folder from https://github.com/curl/curl
2. Delete builds folder
3. Repeat compilation