# How do you install vckpg for Visual Studio Code on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, libcurl

I am trying to install libcurl for my C++ project on VSCode and I came across a method to install via vckpg from this link: [How do you properly install libcurl for use in visual studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861300/how-do-you-properly-install-libcurl-for-use-in-visual-studio-2017)

Hence, I looked for the documentation by Microsoft but only found that you can install vckpg for VSCode for Linux and MacOS but I couldn't find anything on how to install vckpg for VSCode on Windows.

Any idea how do you install vckpg for VSCode on Windows? Or is there an alternative method of installing libcurl on VSCode?

Comment: Following the project https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg I suppose you should do  what it outlines there, although I think this is a question better suited to superuser

Answer (score 2):

Currently VS Code does not support vcpkg on Windows.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/9432) the following issue is directly connected with VS Code support of vcpkg on Windows: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/10217. The issue is currently open and no workaround is provided.

The support may be provided in the future. Here are the comments from the thread:

ghost: "If there are enough requests, a feature request could be initiated to see what would be needed to integrate with CODE RUNNER and/or a plugin for VSCODE."

strega-nil: "Code Runner is not currently a supported way of building with vcpkg; we may add support eventually, but more likely it should be added by the community (or, even better, vcpkg support should be added to Code Runner). However, we do have features hopefully coming down the pipeline which will make life a lot easier for community members adding that support."

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i was struggling with the same issue and installing C++ Redistributable which @mutantkeyboard recommended didn't solve the problem.

I installed VS Community Edition with English language pack and now it's OK.