# HTTP request with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, http, server

I need to send an HTTP request to the server (www.google.com) and get a response. All this I implement in C ++, and I need a library of minimum size.
I tried connecting curl, cpr in Visual Studio, but not successfully.
P.S. I'm new to C ++. Thank you everyone :D

Comment: Sorry, software recommendations are off-topic for stackoverflow.com. You are on the wrong site. You should post this to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What problem did you have with curl, please post a [mre]

Comment: Please describe your problem and post a minimal code that others can copy and paste to reproduce your problem

Comment: Hey Alan Birtles! I can't install curl in Visual Stuido 2019. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You don't install curl "in visual studio". You install the library and tell the visual studio msvc linker tool where to find it.

Comment: Bailey Kocin! How can i install curl in VS?

Comment: so, what i should include? Please, give me you're telegram. Help me plesase. I am beginner and i don't know nothing about lib's and how to includes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can i install curl in VS**

I suggest you could try to use vcpkg to install curl:

1,Get vcpkg from: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/archive/2019.08.zip and extract it to a folder of your choice (e.g. `C:\vcpkg\`)

2,Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 (see Windows Start menu or `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\`) and `cd` to `C:\vcpkg\`

3,Run `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`

4,Run `vcpkg.exe integrate install`

5,Run `vcpkg.exe install curl`

6,And then you could try to use.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680718/11872808

Comment: Oh guy! Thank you very much!) +100 you're karma