# Adding libcurl to Visual Studio 2010, curl/curl.h

Tags: visual-studio-2010, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to add libcurl to a C project in Visual Studio 2010. I was able to find a .lib file, but I still get the following error message:

```
Cannot open include file: 'curl/curl.h'
```

I've tried adding the file to Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, and I've tried adding

```
#pragma comment(lib, "LIBCURL.LIB")
```

to the file in question, but the error still remains. What am I missing?

Comment: Are banned by Google? https://curl.se/mail/lib-2009-04/att-0198/visual_studio_libcurl.pdf The dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861300/how-do-you-properly-install-libcurl-for-use-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: I found that post, but since it's about VS2017, the solution will not work for VS2010. The PDF might be useful, though, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The files I downloaded included the .lib file, but did not have the header files. Grabbing those seems to have fixed the problem.