# How can I link libcurl correctly using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting a linker error when trying to use libcurl.

I have added the input to the lib file in the linker preferences and I have also added the source directory so I don't know why it still won't link.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "curl.h"

int main()
{
 std::cout << LIBCURL_VERSION << std::endl;
 std::cin.get();
 curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
 return 0;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
ConsoleApplication2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_global_init referenced in function _main
C:\Users\paul\Documents\Visual_Studio_2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Again, I have specified the additional directory and the additional input so I don't get why it won't work. Can anybody give me some suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176503/unresolved-symbols-when-linking-a-program-using-libcurl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved symbols when linking a program using libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176503/unresolved-symbols-when-linking-a-program-using-libcurl)